# Android login with email or google example

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin

I want to do a login screen that appears only if the user hasn't already logged in. I want to see a working example because I'm getting an error that I don't know how to fix

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' on a null object reference
```

I want a `NoDisplay` activity to choose if opening the login or main activity. The login screen should have the option to login with email or google. If logging with the google email it should result in the same account as pressing the google sign-in button. The main activity should have a logout button and when pressed it should let the user select a different account in the logging screen.

Comment: Have you called FirebaseApp.initialize?

Comment: provide code for more understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please go through these codes.

```
 this code is used for user registration for the first time     
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            username=(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.rgusername);
            Email=(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.rgemail);
            Password=(TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.rgpassword);
            ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.regibutton);
            mprogress=new ProgressDialog(this);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String Name=username.getText().toString();
                    String email=Email.getText().toString();
                    String pass=Password.getText().toString();

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Name) || TextUtils.isEmpty(email) ||TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Please Fill All the Filds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mprogress.setTitle("Register");
                        mprogress.setMessage("Please Wait While We Create Your Account");
                        mprogress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        mprogress.show();
                        registration(Name,email,pass);
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        private void registration(String name, String email, String pass) {
            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                mprogress.dismiss();
                                Intent main=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                main.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(main);
                                finish();

                            } else {
                                mprogress.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Oop's Error occor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    This code check if the user is loged in or not 

     @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser==null)
            {
                gotostart();
            }
        }

        private void gotostart() {
            Intent start=new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class);
            startActivity(start);
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: feel free to ask if some problem occurs